# rxjs merge not working as expected in angular5

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, merge, rxjs

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/merge';

this.events = this.availableHoursCollection.valueChanges()
this.bla = this.afs.collection<AvailableHour>('users')
  .doc('G2loKLqNQJUQIsDmzSNahlopOyk1').collection('availableHours');

this.test = this.bla.valueChanges();


this.something = Observable.merge(
  this.events,
  this.test
)
```

this.something only has the items of the last observable, how can I combine them?
Also if you have observables with the same value id, how can you merge the values?

Comment: What is `availableHoursCollection`?

Comment: its angular firestore: this.availableHoursCollection = this.afs.collection<AvailableHour>('users').doc(user.uid).collection('availableHours');

Comment: You should investigate whether or not parallel subscriptions to `this.events` and `this.test` both emit changes without being merged. It's highly unlikely that you have found a bug in an operator as fundamental as `merge`. It's more likely that your code is behaving in a manner you are not expecting - for some reason - or that you have found an AngularFire bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using an AngularFire test bed, I ran you Rx scenario

```js
const merged = Observable.merge(o1, o2)
```

and I got an observable which emits twice, each emit containing an array which is the result of each query.

This leads me to wonder how you're checking the output. If piping to a template with the async pipe `{{ results | async }}`, then the second emit will over-write the first and give the impression that only the second emits.

*Apologies if you're well aware of that.*

If you need a single emit of the two arrays combined, there are a number of ways to do so. The best for this scenario is `combineLatest()`.

```js
const combined = Observable.combineLatest(o1, o2)
  .map(([s1, s2]) => [...s1, ...s2])
```

The reason this is best is because `.valueChanges()` is designed to keep pushing changes, so it never completes. So methods based on `forkJoin()` or

```js
Observable.merge(o1.mergeMap(x => x), o2.mergeMap(x => x)).toArray()
```

both require a **completed** event to emit anything, whereas `combineLatest()` does not and the combined observable will emit again whenever one of the sources is updated.

Comment: I was not aware of that, it's all new to me, awesome answer thanks I'll try this tomorrow